# Clean install VestaCP

Tags: mysql, vesta

> i have private server 
> i using SSH for access my server
>  i have remove
>   VestaCP (i using http://vestacp.com/docs/#how-to-uninstall-vesta
>    method) 
>  i using UBUNTU 16.04 LTS

I try to clean up **vestaCP** with this method:

```
apt-get remove --purge nginx apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-common apache2-suexec-custom libapache2-mod-ruid2 libapache2-mod-rpaf libapache2-mod-fcgid bind9 idn mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client php5-common php5-cgi php5-mysql php5-curl libapache2-mod-php5 vsftpd mc exim4 exim4-daemon-heavy clamav-daemon flex dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d phpMyAdmin awstats webalizer jwhois rssh git spamassassin roundcube roundcube-mysql roundcube-plugins sudo bc ftp lsof ntpdate rrdtool dnsutils vesta vesta-nginx vesta-php
```

Then i try to install the VestaCP as usual:

```
curl -O http://vestacp.com/pub/vst-install.sh; bash vst-install.sh --nginx yes --apache yes --phpfpm no --named yes --remi yes --vsftpd yes --proftpd no --iptables yes --fail2ban yes --quota no --exim yes --dovecot yes --spamassassin yes --clamav yes --mysql yes --postgresql yes
```

But I have error at **mysql-server-5.7** as:

> mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11 
>  dpkg: error processing
>   package mysql-server-5.7

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is generic advice from VestaCP in their documentation:

// Perhaps try stopping mysql-server, apache2, and nginx as well, just incase they're holding up the uninstall. Also, can you post the output/errors if any?

1. Stop vesta service
   `service vesta stop`
2. Remove vesta packages and software repository

   **RHEL/CentOS:**
   `yum remove vesta*`
    `rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/vesta.repo`
   Debian/Ubuntu:
   `apt-get remove vesta*`
   `rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vesta.list`
3. Delete data directory and cron

   `rm -rf /usr/local/vesta`

Honestly, if you're at a point where you can purge all these files, it's probably easier to reinstall your operating system. Failing that, get another VPS(Virtual Private Server) on the go.
Install Vesta on the new server, apply any backups of your website(s) and database(s), and then install/setup any services (other than Vesta) you had running on the current server.

If that is completely out of the question, you can find out exactly which packages it installs depending on which version and linux distribution you use. For example the [click here](http://vestacp.com/pub/vst-install-ubuntu.sh) for the Ubuntu version.

Just underneath `if [ "$release" = '16.04' ]; then` is the block of software that the script apt-get installs.

Comment: I had to run full purge, not only remove vesta*:

apt-get purge -y vesta* maria* libmysql* mysql* nginx apache2* exim* dovecot* && apt-get autoremove -y && rm -rf /etc/apache2

Answer (score -2):

Try using --force with your install command or reinstall ubuntu

Comment: Please don't sign your posts. That's what your profile is for.